# Scala overloaded constructors and super

Tags: scala, constructor, super, constructor-overloading

I can't understand how to develop Scala code similar to the following on Java:

```
public abstract class A {
   protected A() { ... }
   protected A(int a) { ... }
}

public abstract class B {
   protected B() { super(); }
   protected B(int a) { super(a); }
}

public class C extends B {
   public C() { super(3); }
}
```

while it's clear how to develop C class, I can't get how to receive B. Help, please.

P.S. I'm trying to create my own BaseWebPage derived from wicket WebPage which is a common practice for Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
abstract class A protected (val slot: Int) {
    protected def this() = this(0)
}

abstract class B protected (value: Int) extends A(value) {
    protected def this() = this(0)
}

class C extends B(3) {
}
```

There is, AFAIK, no way to bypass the primary constructor from one of the secondary forms, i.e., the following will not work:

```
abstract class B protected (value: Int) extends A(value) {
    protected def this() = super()
}
```

All secondary constructor forms must call the primary one. From the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (5.3.1 Constructor Definitions):

> A class may have additional constructors besides the primary constructor. These
>   are deﬁned by constructor deﬁnitions of the form def this(ps1)...(psn) = e.
>   Such a deﬁnition introduces an additional constructor for the enclosing class, with
>   parameters as given in the formal parameter lists ps1, ..., psn, and whose evaluation
>   is deﬁned by the constructor expression e. The scope of each formal parameter is
>   the subsequent parameter sections and the constructor expression e. **A constructor
>   expression is either a self constructor invocation this(args1)...(argsn) or a block
>   which begins with a self constructor invocation**

(emphasis mine).

Comment: thank you for clarification!
is there a scala way to implement that? the point is not call another constructor of myself, but the one from superclass.

Comment: [No.](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-calling-different-super-constructors-td1994456.html)