# Alternative Constructor in Abstract Class Scala

Tags: java, scala, oop

Suppose I have a class and I want to be able to make new instances by passing an old instance and some new piece of data. Additionally I have an `abstract` class from which other classes will inherit, I want this copying behavior to be implemented in the abstract class.

This can be accomplished in Java like so

```
evan@vbox ~/junk > cat Test.java
public abstract class Test
{
        public String name;
        public String data;

        /* Standard Constructor */
        public Test(String name, String data)
        {
                this.name = name;
                this.data = data;
        }

        /* "Copy" constructor: old instance data is copied, except this.data*/
        public Test(Test oldInst, String newData)
        {
                /* Copy unchanged data from old instance */
                this.name = oldInst.name;

                /* Insert new data */
                this.data = newData;
        }

        /* Derived classes will implement this */
        public abstract void identify();
}

evan@vbox ~/junk > cat Test_Inh.java
public class Test_Inh extends Test
{
        public Test_Inh(String name, String data)
        {
                super(name, data);
        }

        public Test_Inh(Test_Inh oldInst, String newData)
        {
                super(oldInst, newData);
        }

        public void identify()
        {
                System.out.println("This is a Test_Inh with properties:\n\tName: " 
                + this.name + "\n\tData: " + this.data);
        }
}

evan@vbox ~/junk > cat Main.java
public class Main
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                Test_Inh t1 = new Test_Inh("name", "original data");
                t1.identify();

                Test_Inh t2 = new Test_Inh(t1, "new data");
                t2.identify();
        }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
evan@vbox ~/junk > javac *.java && java Main
This is a Test_Inh with properties:
        Name: name
        Data: original data
This is a Test_Inh with properties:
        Name: name
        Data: new data
```

I would like to implement this behavior in Scala, however there is no access to super constructors from child classes. It is my understanding that alternate constructors should be handled by a companion object or a factory in Scala. However neither of these makes sense when working with an abstract class.

Comment: I'm sorry I may have chosen the wrong dupe. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623059/scala-overloaded-constructors-and-super. Which one solves the issue?

Comment: Hmm, yes it appears that what I am trying to do is not possible. Is there a way to salvage this question and ask how to emulate the desired behavior given the known limitation?

Comment: Sure. I can reopen it if you'd like to just edit it. Should I do that? Or you could delete it and ask a new one. Or you could leave it and ask a new one. Up to you.

Comment: I'll think about it and create a new question which will be more clear. Thanks!